# Using Coordinator Layout to move floating action button when a custom popup animates

Tags: android, popup, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

Long story short, can you get the floatingActionButton to move up and down when a custom view is moved up and down in the same way as it does with the snackbar?

I have a Floating Action Button in a coordinator layout that moves up when the snackbar is shown. I've even managed to customize the FABs "Behaviour" through tutorials to make it shrink and grow rather than move up and down.

I also have a custom made popup (LinearLayout) that animates up from the bottom and back down again when a button is pressed and that currently just pops up behind the floating action button which doesn't move. Both are in a CoordinatorLayout I would like the floating action button to go up and down when the custom popup animates up and down...in the same way it does for the snackbar.

I've kind of managed to get it to work by adding my custom popup as a dependency on calls to the layoutDependsOn method of the FloatingActionButton behaviour class. However my implementation for the onDependentViewChanged method to actually get the FAB to animate up and down just feels wrong as i'm effectively having to animate the floatingActionButton seperately with the a coordinated animation to match the custom popups animation.

Can anybody point me at how to do this better and more easily?

I'll try to provide meaningful code snippets....

**custom popup:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:id="@+id/selected_item_popup_linear_layout"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:visibility="gone"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/selectedItemPopupBackground" android:elevation="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/selected_item_popup_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/selected_item_popup_delete_button"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"
        android:background="@color/selectedItemPopupBackground"
        android:tint="@color/selectedItemPopupDeleteTint"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/selected_item_popup_edit_button"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_black_24dp"
        android:background="@color/selectedItemPopupBackground"
        android:tint="@color/selectedItemPopupEditTint"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Floating action button:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floating_action_button_add_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/pager"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:layout_behavior=".FloatingActionButtonBehaviour"
    app:rippleColor="@color/boardItemBackgroundSelected"/>
```

**Floating Action Button Behaviour:**

```
    public class FloatingActionButtonBehaviour extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FloatingActionButton> {

    private Context mContext;

    public FloatingActionButtonBehaviour(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {

        if (dependency.equals(parent.findViewById(R.id.selected_item_popup_linear_layout))) {
            return true;
        }

        if (dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, final FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {

        if(dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) {

            float translationY = getFabTranslationYForSnackbar(parent, child);
            float percentComplete = -translationY / dependency.getHeight();
            float scaleFactor = 1 - percentComplete;

            child.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            child.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
        }

        if (dependency.equals(parent.findViewById(R.id.selected_item_popup_linear_layout))) {

            View contentView = dependency.findViewById(R.id.selected_item_popup_content);
            int contentViewHeight = contentView.getHeight();

            if (dependency.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

                Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.fab_move_up);
                child.startAnimation(bottomUp);
                child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                float translationY = Math.min(0, dependency.getTranslationY() - contentViewHeight);
                child.setTranslationY(translationY);

            } else {

                Animation bottomDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.fab_move_down);
                child.startAnimation(bottomDown);
                child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                child.setTranslationY(dependency.getTranslationY());
            }

        }

        return true;

    }

    private float getFabTranslationYForSnackbar(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton fab) {
        float minOffset = 0;
        final List<View> dependencies = parent.getDependencies(fab);
        for (int i = 0, z = dependencies.size(); i < z; i++) {
            final View view = dependencies.get(i);
            if (view instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout && parent.doViewsOverlap(fab, view)) {
                minOffset = Math.min(minOffset, ViewCompat.getTranslationY(view) - view.getHeight());
            }
        }

        return minOffset;
    }
}
```

**Code to Animate the custom popup:**

```
        Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mActivity, R.anim.bottom_up);
    final ViewGroup selectedItemPopupLinearLayout = (ViewGroup)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.selected_item_popup_linear_layout);
    selectedItemPopupLinearLayout.startAnimation(bottomUp);
    selectedItemPopupLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I found my answer in BottomSheets/ModalSheets....

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#bottom-sheets

Not tried it yet but it looks the business